# what is the default code for gradle

Tags: gradle

I was asked a very awesome question from someone starting to use gradle and I realize it would be extremely cool and probably already exists.

When we go to override a task like jar, many times you want to actually see the original gradle code that is used for the jar task or compileJava task.  Does such a thing exist?  (or did they end up writing that stuff in java).  If that does exist, please give us a link? and it would be awesome to wire into the command line or documentation online(or maybe it is wired in somewhere and I missed it as the documentation online is one huge book, which is great, don't get me wrong.).

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is on github, as detailed on [the web site](http://www.gradle.org/development), so you can easily check it out and grep for specific implementations.

For example [this is the code for the Jar task](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/plugins/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/tasks/bundling/Jar.groovy).

The Gradle build language you use in your scripts is a DSL implemented in Groovy and Java. The [language reference](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/) is a useful resource for mapping between the stuff you write in your project and the API docs for the underlying code.

Comment: Gradle *is-a* build tool, and *has-a* Groovy DSL. :-)

Comment: Ok, I guess I was referring to the idea of "gradle code" from the question. Obviously gradle is a lot more than a DSL :-).

Comment: Not sure if it's obvious to everyone. I often hear people say that Gradle is a build DSL, Spock is a test DSL, etc.